# handler: 'html', size: {x: 265, y: 650} to 100%

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, slimbox

I need help with. I need to get y: 650 to 100% but it wont allow me to enter something like 100% is there any other way to this please.

```
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {



                var responce = request.responseText;
                var options = {url: detailurl, handler: 'html', size: {x: 265, y: 650}, htmldata: responce,pid:product_id};
                redBOX.initialize({});
                document.attbox = redBOX.open(null, options);

                // preload slimbox
                var imagehandle = {isenable: false, mainImage: false};
                preloadSlimbox(imagehandle);

                var el = RedgetElementsByClassName('calendar');

                for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
                    // do stuff here with myEls[i]
                    var calImgId = el[i].id;
                    arr = calImgId.split("_img");
                    n = arr.length;
                    var calName = arr[0];
                    var realname = calName.split("ajax");

                    if ((calImgId.search('ajax') != -1) && (extrafieldNames.search(realname[0]) != -1)) {
                        window.addEvent('domready', function () {
                            Calendar.setup({
                                inputField: calName,     // id of the input field
                                ifFormat: "%d-%m-%Y",      // format of the input field

                                button: el[i].id,  // trigger for the calendar (button ID)
                                align: "Tl",           // alignment (defaults to "Bl")
                                singleClick: true
                            });
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with javasript:

size: {x: 265, y: parseInt(document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.width)}

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried use:

```
$('html').width()
```

For example:

```
size: {x: 265, y: $('html').width()}
```

Comment: Yes of course, it was some of the first things that showed up on my google search. And no it didnt help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
size: {x: 265, y: $('html').css('width')}
```

For set the width you can try

```
 size: {x: 265, y: $('html').css('width','100%')}
```

Comment: Sorry but that did not work, the box will not even apear if i try to edit anything. beside from x: Number, y: Number

I admit that this kind of code is not my strong side of the force.